# The aria-expanded shows false even when the element is expanded

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, wai-aria

I want to know why the aria is not expanded when clicking.

```html
<div 
    class="tooltip filter-tooltip" 
    tabindex="0" 
    role="button" 
    aria-label="Vaccine Brand More Information" 
    aria-expanded="false" 
    aria-controls="filter_dialog"
\>
```

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: What are you talking about? Aria doesn't _add_ interaction to your site, it is used to define accessibility guidelines for the browser. Changing values in aria is up to the developer. What are you even expecting will/should happen?

Answer (score 1):

That attribute won't change its value by itself. You need to add some steps to your script that change the attribute to "true"  when you click the element to expand, and back to "false" when you click again to close it.

Answer (score 1):

[ARIA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA) is a set of attributes that define ways to make web content and web applications more accessible to people with disabilities.

### Aria expanded

> The [`aria-expanded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-expanded) attribute is set on an element to indicate if a control is expanded or collapsed, and whether or not its child elements are displayed or hidden.

So **you're the one** supposed to change that value based on whether the content is expanded.

### Aria owns

> There are two declarations that can be applied to objects that control the visibility of another object: `aria-controls`, or `aria-owns` combined with `aria-expanded`.

If an element visually, functionally, or contextually appears to "own" (be an ancestor of) an element, but isn't actually an ancestor of the element in the DOM, include the `aria-owns` to create that relationship.

So you also need to add `aria-owns` which includes the id of the children if you're going to use `aria-expanded`.

```html
<div 
  class="tooltip filter-tooltip" 
  tabindex="0" 
  role="button" 
  aria-label="Vaccine Brand More Information" 
  aria-expanded="false" 
  aria-controls="filter_dialog"
  aria-owns="children"
\>
<div id="children"> 
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Monstar is correct: the aria-expanded attribute is only a way to make your page more accessible to people with disabilities. It should be `true` when the default of the collapsable item is expanded (i.e. is shown). It should be `false` when the default of the collapsable item is collapsed (i.e hidden).

**To change the default behaviour of the collapsable item in Bootstrap 5**, you have to add or remove the class `show` to the collapsable item. E.g.

```
<div class="collapse show multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample1">
// collapsable item will be shown by default
</div>

<div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample1">
// collapsable item will be hidden by default
</div
```